# How can I get the customer ID in a cached block when full page cache is enabled?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

When the full page cache is enabled Magento disabled the PHP sessions, this way I am unable to load the customer session and get the user ID.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this. It could be useful to you guys.

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;

/**
 * @param HttpContext $httpContext
 */
public function __construct(HttpContext $httpContext) 
{
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}


/**
 * @return bool
 */
private function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
}
```

If you want to force the start of the php session you could inject the class `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager` in the constructor
and use `$this->session->start()`

```
    if (null === $customerId) {
        if ($this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            if (!$this->session->isSessionExists()) {
                $this->session->start();
            }

            $visitorData = $this->session->getData('visitor_data');
            if (isset($visitorData['customer_id'])) {
                $customerId = $visitorData['customer_id'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you not use `$this->session->getCustomerId()` ?

Comment: You can not use httpContext to get customer id. Even if you would give it an own Vary String then it would create a new cached page for every customer